# Erlang sellaprime OTP application

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm trying to run the sellaprime example OTP application from Chapter 23 of Programming Erlang 2nd Ed.  I have uploaded the code to https://github.com/myles-mcdonnell/sellaprime

After compiling with rebar I run erl from the root, then switch dir ..

```
1> c(src).
/Users/mylesmcdonnell/sellaprime/src
ok
```

then I load the app..

```
2> application:load(sellaprime).
ok
```

then I try to start the app..

```
3> application:start(sellaprime).

=CRASH REPORT==== 5-Feb-2015::09:55:34 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.48.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {bad_return,
                        {{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                         {'EXIT',
                             {undef,
                                 [{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]],[]},
                                  {application_master,start_supervisor,3,
                                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                       {line,326}]},
                                  {application_master,start_the_app,5,
                                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                       {line,308}]},
                                  {application_master,start_it_new,7,
                                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                       {line,294}]}]}}}}
      in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 133)
    ancestors: [<0.47.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.49.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.47.0>,<0.7.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 610
    stack_size: 27
    reductions: 124
  neighbours:

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Feb-2015::09:55:34 ===
    application: sellaprime
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {undef,
                         [{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]],[]},
                          {application_master,start_supervisor,3,
                              [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,326}]},
                          {application_master,start_the_app,5,
                              [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,308}]},
                          {application_master,start_it_new,7,
                              [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                               {line,294}]}]}}}}
    type: temporary
{error,
    {bad_return,
        {{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]]},
         {'EXIT',
             {undef,
                 [{sellaprime_app,start,[normal,[]],[]},
                  {application_master,start_supervisor,3,
                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,326}]},
                  {application_master,start_the_app,5,
                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,308}]},
                  {application_master,start_it_new,7,
                      [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,294}]}]}}}}}
```

Clearly something is undefined but I'm struggling to determine what? I have lifted the code directly from the book download site with no changes.

Comment: The function `start/2` in the module `sellaprime_app` is undefined, or the module is not loaded. Presumably it's because the `.beam` file is not in the code path. You can check the code path with `code:get_path/0`, and add directories with [`code:add_path/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#add_path-1) or with the `-pa` command line switch to `erl`.

Comment: thanks, yes it turned out to be environmental not code.